# Alert! Incompatible processor detected

Tags: processor-socket, lga775

I recently got my new Intel core 2 extreme (3.0Ghz, LGA775) and have just installed it

When turning on the pc is says this:

"Alert! Incompatible processor detected.

System Halted!"

I'm running a Dell optiplex 760 with 6GB DDR2 ram

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to get rid of this error so I can boot into windows

Comment: Install a compatible processor?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this one is compatible, it uses the LGA775 socket and went into the port fine.

Comment: @Mrfunny744 That doesn't mean that the BIOS knows what the processor is or how to correctly configure it. If you update your BIOS from your manufacturer and still get this error, then you need to find a processor that *is* supported as this one isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Even though they use the same socket (LGA 775), *Core 2 Extreme* processors are not compatible with all of the chipsets used by *Core 2 Duo* and *Quad* processors.

Here's a diagram showing the chipsets supported by the QX6800, Q6700, and E6600 processors. As you can see, even *Core 2* processors in the same series (6xxx) don't all support the same chipsets.

[image: Venn diagram of chipsets supported by Core 2 Duo E6600, Core 2 Quad Q6700, and Core 2 Extreme QX6800.]

This information is all available from [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com).

The problem will be that the motherboard you are using does not have a chipset that is compatible with the processor you are using, and hence it cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

I am late but when it says system halted press F2 and it will start booting with the core 2 extreme

It's a ghetto solution but works.